# When could we get $f' = f^{-1}$, where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f$, and not $\frac{1}{f}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Personal question :** Is there a general solution to the equation $f' = f^{-1}$, where $f^{-1}$
>   is the inverse function of $f$, and not $\frac{1}{f}$.

I think this question is difficult, and I don't have the competence to answer it.

Are there someone who is able to rigorously answer this question?

Comment: With "When could we get..." do you mean for us to (try to) find _all_ solutions or _some_ solution?

Comment: @Wojowu I wish I had a general solution to this question.

Comment: We have $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, so we have $f'(f^{-1}(x))\cdot (f^{-1})'(x)=1=f^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))\cdot (f^{-1})'(x)$.

Comment: @abiessu Functional inverse is a function satisfying $f^{-1}(f(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x$.

Comment: I worked hard to find a solution, but honnestly I got no significant results.

Comment: possibly useful remark:   we have $f\circ f' = id\implies f''=\frac 1{f'\circ f'}$ so taking $F=f'$ we are lead to $F'=\frac 1 {F\circ F}$.  Now the similar equation $f'=f\circ f $ has been written about, eg, here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111066/is-there-any-techniques-for-solving-a-differential-equation-including-iterated-f   Perhaps similar methods apply.

Comment: One solution on $(0,+\infty)$ is $f(x) = \phi^{1-\phi}\cdot x^{\phi}$ where $\phi = \frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}$. Then $f'(x) = \phi^{2-\phi}\cdot x^{\phi-1}$ and $f(f'(x)) = \phi^{1-\phi}\cdot (\phi^{2-\phi}x^{\phi-1})^{\phi} = \phi^{1-\phi + 2\phi - \phi^2}x^{\phi^2-\phi} = x$. Since clearly both $f$ and $f'$ are bijective, it follows that $f' = f^{-1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How did you find this solution?

Comment: @Ovi The derivatives as well as the inverses of functions of the form $x\mapsto c\cdot x^{\alpha}$ ($\alpha \neq -1$) are of the same form. So it just remained to determine the suitable coefficient and exponent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think any such function is possible, at least if the domain of $f$ is supposed to be all of $\mathbb{R}$. If $f^{-1}$ is defined, then $f$ is injective, and if $f$ is also continuous, this means that $f$ is monotone, so either $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ or $f'(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$. Either way, $f'$ is not surjective, but $f^{-1}$ must be surjective (since $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$), so $f' \neq f^{-1}$.

Comment: This gives rise to whether this is possible if we ask for $f'$ to be _one-sided_ inverse of $f$ (so that we require only $f(f'(x))=x$).