# Solving $f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

This is a problem that a friend of mine gave to me a while back. I somewhat solved it and paid no attention to it afterwards until I though about it now. Forgive the errors and laziness this was a long time ago and not everything has to be perfect.

I assumed $f$ to be a polynomial function of the kind $f(x)=ax^b$ where $f^{-1}(x)= \big(\frac x a\big)^{1/b} $ and found
$$f(x)= \varphi^{-\frac{1}{\varphi}-1}(-x)^{\phi} $$

where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\phi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ my working is in the following images : (I did this in word)

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

I was curious if there were more solutions to just this polynomial? Perhaps a different function ?

Don't bother commenting trying to correct my work I am just curious about the above questions. Thank you for your time

Comment: Relevant MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f

Comment: @lc2r43 Thank you

Comment: Previous discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735695/function-whose-inverse-is-also-its-derivative, other same questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660413/when-could-we-get-f-f-1-where-f-1-is-the-inverse-function-of-f, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916191/ode-with-inverse-function-solve-f-1x-fx

Comment: Michael Penn takes a look at it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNUfiQgj6ZI